# JQuery syntax for finding if an element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find a form inside of a div on a webpage using JQuery. I have the following:

```
alert('in');
alert($('#prodForm').length == 0);
alert('made it past');
```

When the script executes, I see the 'in' printed out, but I never see the 'made it past' get printed, leading me to believe there is a problem with my 2nd line, where I am trying to determine if the form exists. The form has an id of prodForm.

Am I missing something syntactically?

Comment: did you have a look at your console? Press F12 in Chrome

Comment: `length` works, the value is an array.

Comment: The code is right. You don't receive errors? Using chrome, it may be blocking alerts for anti-spam purposes. Check for errors in your console.

Comment: maybe not using last jquery version?

Comment: Try running this JS: `alert($ === jQuery);`  If you see a popup with `false`, it means `$` isn't set to the `jQuery` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('div').has('#prodForm').length != 0); // the form exists
```

Comment: This will result in the number of div elements that have a descendant with the id prodForm.

Comment: so you can use length as a flag of existence, right?

Comment: Yeah, if > 0 your code proves that there is a #prodForm on the page, I just don't think your approach adds any value compared to OP's already correct code, plus the results of your snippet is a bit harder to interpret.

Comment: Yeap, you're right, my fault. Should change to:

    alert($('div').has('#prodForm').length != 0); // the form exists

Answer (score 0):

Apparently JQuery wasn't loaded, I am building a chrome plugin, and I had to list jquery BEFORE my javascript file

Answer (score -2):

```
alert('in');
alert($('#prodForm').size() == 0);
alert('made it past');
```